# jQuery Mobile / JSON

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

All,
I have couple of questions regarding jQuery Mobile/JSON, I'd like to create a mobile application for an existing website that does not have JSON plugin, and have these 2 questions:

1. How to add JSON plugin to an existing website that was not build using Wordpress?
2. Within the mobile app I'm creating, when I add below anchor, and click on the button, I get "Error loading page", so confused why this is happening. Is there a way to point the anchor to an existing page(i.e. to yahoo.com for example)?

`<a href="www.leparisien.fr" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Home</a>`

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not clear what JSON plugin has to do with your intention to build JQM application. What tools you can leverage for your JQM app depends on many factors some of which are what platform, technologies, tools were used to build your current site, what is your mobile content strategy etc.
2. There is an error in `href` attribute of your anchor tag.

Possible values for `href`:

- An absolute URL - points to another web site (like  href="http://www.example.com/default.htm")
- A relative URL - points to a file within a web site (like href="default.htm")
- An anchor URL - points to an anchor within a page (like href="#top")

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp)

So that will do

```html
<a href="http://www.leparisien.fr" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r">Home</a>
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/jnK5T/) for you

Comment: Thanks peterm for your answer. If I want the external site to be opened in your mobile page, what is the best way to do this please, for example taking your example by keeping the header and footer, then display the external page as a content.